# Can i run testcafe regularly at time, day, or personal routine

Tags: testcafe

Can i run testcafe regularly at time, day, or personal routine?

I want to make codeless tests created with testcafe or testcafe run automatically
at the time or day of the week I want.

I need this funtion.

I dont know, how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to incorporate TestCafe into your routine, such as scheduling tests or running them after pull requests, it is recommended to use continuous integration (CI) services. These services allow the automation of code changes and the building and testing of applications. Here is the link to the official documentation on how to integrate TestCafe into a build process on popular continuous integration systems.
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402809/guides/continuous-integration

In addition, if you are using codeless tests, see this article:
https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400445/advanced-capabilities/integrate-tests-with-ci-systems